# Does writing code in viewDidLoad Violates MVC architecture?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I was working in a client project. I have written lot many view customisation code inside `ViewDidLoad`. I have models for data store and access.
The project was working fine. They hired a new iOS developer he said the code is not compliant with MVC architecture. The asked the reason why? He said the views are created inside `viewDidLoad` which is a controller of the Class hence it is not acceptable code. What should we do when its really dynamic views and can not be created using storyboard.

Comment: Did you ask his opinion?

Comment: You can create classes for each view, which you are creating dynamically. then you easily import them into your controller.

Comment: He works remotely . But the sole reason of denying that the code is not in MVC is that I created some views inside view DidLoad. Only question that stroke in my mind is" In iOS application development If I write view creation code inside ViewDidLoad does it violate MVC architecture?"

Comment: Yes. As per the MVC model, each class in your project is either a Controller, a Model or a View; don’t combine the functionality of two roles in one class.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is **No**

From apple doc

> Controller Objects
>
> A controller object acts as an intermediary between one or more of an application’s view objects and one or more of its model objects. Controller objects are thus a conduit through which view objects learn about changes in model objects and vice versa. Controller objects can also perform setup and coordinating tasks for an application and manage the life cycles of other objects.

I think that the controller has the responsibility to manage what the view look like.

In `viewDidLoad`,it is good to write **one-time** view customisation code here.

But if you write a lot configuration code to a view. I think it is better to use a subclass of UIView. This makes your code clear and easy to debug and maintain.

Comment: This is what exactly I thought . Sorry due to low reputation could not up vote.

Comment: @DipeshPokhrel but you can accept that answer if it is correct for you. WenchenHuang what is the question for your bold __NO__ answer? OP's question asks "What should we do?"

Comment: His question is "Does writing code in viewDidLoad Violates MVC architecture?"

Comment: The explanation that has been provided is very satisfactory for me. It seems I am violating the MVC pattern but in case the very less customisation of views inside ViewDidLoad could be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You can make differentiate between Controller and View in this way -

Use `- (void)loadView {}` delegate method to load your view from `viewcontroller`.

Suppose you have a view class -

CustomView.h 
CustomView.m -

```
- (id)init {

    return [self initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        // Initialization code
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [self addSubview:self.centerView];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Now in your ViewController -

```
- (void)loadView
{
    self.view = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
}
```

Please refer below url for more details - 
http://matthewmorey.com/creating-uiviews-programmatically-with-auto-layout/

Hope this can be help you.

Answer (score 0):

You would ideally have a dedicated class for your main view (the one that's accessed by self.view inside viewcontroller) - derived from UIView.

Inside this view class (say Myview.m) - you will create its subviews inside various view methods - such as `init` (for instantiation of subviews), `layoutsubviews` (for frame setting of subviews) and `drawrect` (any graphics drawing etc.) If the view has NIB, some processing will go inside awakeFromNib too.